# Ubuntu 15.04 & 15.10 - Bluetooth Logitech Ultrathin Touch Mouse t630 - Extream Lag

Tags: 15.04, mouse, dell, bluetooth, 15.10

**UPDATE:**

The problem seems to be related to the fact that I have a Broadcom wireless card. I have issues with every Bluetooth device I try to connect to. :(

Updating to Ubuntu 15.10 has not fixed the problem ether.

---

My computer is the Dell Precision M3800 and I am dual booting a clean install of Ubuntu 15.04 64-bit and Windows 10.
My mouse is the Logitech Ultrathin touch Mouse t630 connected via Bluetooth.

<del>Upon booting into Ubuntu and connecting my mouse it seems to work fine.</del> *(Not even this is working any more.)*

However if I connect to it some time after I've booted Ubuntu or after I've suspended the computer, the mouse becomes super laggy making it unusable.

Also note that logging in and out does not fix the problem.

On a side note, why do I have to press the pairing button on my mouse each time before it will connect?

Thanks for any help!

**Edit:** This might be helpful:

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net
06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43b1] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0019]
    Kernel driver in use: wl

$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a5c:216f Broadcom Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f3:21e5 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:573c Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Have you tried in Ubuntu 15.10? Works great for me -- automatically connects after reboot, natural scrolling, left-right scolling, gesture to open start menu all work. (The switch-app gesture appears to be bound to forward / back navigation in the browser).  I have it paired to XPS 13 with an intel bluetooth chip.

Comment: @cboettig Yes, I have updated to Ubuntu 15.10, however the problems still continue and seems to effect every Bluetooth device I try. It's probably because I have a Broadcom wireless chip. :(
Also, I have returned the mouse back to the store.

Comment: Yeah, I swapped out the broadcom chip right away. $20 gets you a much nicer, faster, longer range wifi card+bluetooth; how-to is documented in the xps 13 manual and appears not to void any warranty, so kudos to Dell for that at least.

Answer (score 0):

i have the "same" problems with this mouse.

sometimes it is unusable because if i scroll, it seems to send other commands, like mouse-drag (hold down left mouse button) and ESC keypress. if i then press ESC, it seems to work again for some time until the same behaviour occurs.
sometimes the problems are occuring more often if the mouse-battery get's lower.
but actually it is unusable with 50% of capacity.
it also seems that the mouse isn't correctly recognized by gnome-power-statistics -> i.e. it says Energy: 0,0 Wh and Energy (Design): 0,0 Wh...
Don't know if this has to do with the problems?!

Comment: I'm not having anything like the issues you are having. For me the correct commands are being sent. Charging the mouse doesn't seem to fix the problem. Unity's battery indicator works great with the mouse and shows the correct charge level. (Although it thinks it's a laptop battery). The only thing for me is that all the mouse events are taking a long time to send to X.

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed this last night with my MX Revolution.  Here's what I found on a french site:

Edit /lib/udev/rules.d/97-hid2hci.rules

Change this line:

```
KERNEL=="hiddev*", ATTRS{idVendor}=="046d", ATTRS{idProduct}=="c70[345abce]|c71[3bc]", \
  RUN+="hid2hci --method=logitech-hid --devpath=%p"
```

to be this (Change hiddev* to hidraw*):

```
KERNEL=="hiddev*", ATTRS{idVendor}=="046d", ATTRS{idProduct}=="c70[345abce]|c71[3bc]", \
  RUN+="hid2hci --method=logitech-hid --devpath=%p"
```